# htacces multiple rewrite rules not working with RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so, i created an htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?paramOne=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?paramOne=$1&paramTwo=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?paramOne=$1&paramTwo=$2&paramThree=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?paramOne=$1&paramTwo=$2&paramThree=$3&paramFour=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?paramOne=$1&paramTwo=$2&paramThree=$3&paramFour=$4&paramFive=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?paramOne=$1&paramTwo=$2&paramThree=$3&paramFour=$4&paramFive=$5&paramSix=$6 [L]
```

the reason is have multiple of the same things, is so that i dont have to fill all the url params,

only problem is that i get 404 page still even after using this method,

if i use 1 rewrite method with all the params, i have to fill each one,

how may i beable to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your htaccess here, please do mention what should be the condition to re-write your urls to backend urls? For better understanding of question.

Comment: hmm, what do you mean. all i know is that i have rewritten get variables and putt the values on to some vars with if(isset()).

Comment: Rule don't like right. Provide example of URLs causing 404

Comment: also, im not sure and dont know much about htaccess or mod_rewrite, i used this generator to get these results.https://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Comment: heres the url layout, there are 6 parameters, the first one being for the page u want to see, then the other 5 are params tht can be used in the page.
xenonmc.tk/register/verifyaccount/Xfaon/(token)/(secretToken)/more params/sadad

Comment: heres is a url casuign 404
xenonmc.tk/register/verifyaccount/Xfaon/(token)/(secretToken)/more params/sadad
xenonmc.tk/register/verifyaccount/Xfaon/(token)/(secretToken)/more params
the top one is workign but the second one isnt becuause now param 6 is blank, and it leades meto 404

Comment: Why are you using same pattern in all rules? Your request will only match the first rule.

Comment: the reason i havethe same paterns, is because first i rewrite 1 rule then in the next one 2 rules then 3 then 4 and so on, in my oldhosting, this used to fx my issue, but now i  have switched to 000webhostand got this issue, my old hosting used appache and xampp doesnt seem to have a problem running my site. neither did my old hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your rules are using same pattern, which is not right.

It should be written like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ?paramOne=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?paramOne=$1&paramTwo=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]=)/?$ ?paramOne=$1&paramTwo=$2&paramThree=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?paramOne=$1&paramTwo=$2&paramThree=$3&paramFour=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?paramOne=$1&paramTwo=$2&paramThree=$3&paramFour=$4&paramFive=$5 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?paramOne=$1&paramTwo=$2&paramThree=$3&paramFour=$4&paramFive=$5&paramSix=$6 [L,QSA]
```